# IE11 DOM normalize doesn't work with table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, dom, normalize

I'd like to normalize table rows. This works like a charm, except in IE (tested with IE 11).

I've created a demo snippet to demonstrate the issue:

```js
$(function() {
  $("table tbody tr span").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $parent = $this.parent();
    $this.replaceWith($this.html());
    $parent[0].normalize();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>President</th>
      <th>Birthplace</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span>Zach</span>ary Taylor</td>
      <td>Barboursville, Virginia</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This replaces the `<span>` element with its content. After this step the node will look like:

[image: DOM Node]

Then, `normalize()` is called to merge the splitted text nodes. However, in IE11 the text nodes are still splitted.

I can't see any issue from my side. What's the cause of this problem and what could be the solution?

---

As it turned out that this is a IE11 bug, I've filled in a **[bug report](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8727426/)**!

Comment: did you check the updated answer? I would like to know if it answers your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like IE-11 can't normalize elements that are already part of your document **If your developers toolbar is open**.

> This is also relevant for IE9 & 10 (emulated by using `meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"` tag)

When you only create new nodes and you don't attach them to the document - everything works great (for both situations - developers toolbar is open and close):

```js
d = document.createElement('div');
d.appendChild(document.createTextNode('text 1'));
d.appendChild(document.createTextNode('text 2'));
console.log(d.childNodes.length + ' - Should be 2')
d.normalize();
console.log(d.childNodes.length + ' - Should be 1')
```

If, however, you are working with nodes that are already part of your document, the `normalize` function doesn't work **if your developer toolbar is open**:

```js
d = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
d.appendChild(document.createTextNode('text 1'));
d.appendChild(document.createTextNode('text 2'));
console.log(d.childNodes.length + ' - should be 2 on every browser')
d.normalize();
console.log(d.childNodes.length + ' - should be 1, however it\'s 2 on IE')
```

```html
<div></div>
```

If you really want, what you can do is extract the nodes from the document and add them after you normalize them:

```js
d = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
d.appendChild(document.createTextNode('text 1'));
d.appendChild(document.createTextNode('text 2'));
console.log(d.childNodes.length + ' - should be 2 on every browser')

dNew = d.cloneNode(true)
dNew.normalize()
d.parentElement.replaceChild(dNew, d)

d = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
console.log(d.childNodes.length + ' - should be 1 on every browser')
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Update - 28/8**
Answer was updated after the comment from @dude. It took some time to investigate the cause here, but I think that now I covered everything.

> Note that for IE8 (forced by using `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">` in IE-11) the `normalize()` function works for both elements that are in the DOM tree and elements that are not, even with the developers toolbar was open.

Comment: `It seems like IE-11 can't normalize elements that are already part of your document.`. This isn't true, `normalize()` works in IE 11 e.g. with a paragraph: https://jsfiddle.net/zpsbxhy1/ And your first example works for me too.

Comment: @dude, you are correct. I did a more thorough check and I think I found the cause (and solution if you need). You are welcome to check and let me know (if it's correct - please wait with the awarding of the bounty until it's over to see if someone else has something more to say regarding this weird situation).

Comment: I can't confirm that this is only appearing when the developer toolbar is open. For me the issue exists even when the developer toolbar isn't open. What browser/os are you using? As you can see in my above example it works with e.g. a `<p>` element. There must be a reason why this doesn't work in table contexts.

Comment: @dude _"works in IE 11 e.g. with a paragraph: jsfiddle ..."_ Your example does NOT work in IE11.

Comment: @dude, I'm using IE11 on Win 8. From all the checks that I did it seems like a bug in IE. In several of my checks the browsers didn't give exactly the expected result, so between open/close the developers tool bar I switch websites (open dev tool -> open test page -> close dev tool -> go open google.com -> open test page). Can you try that and let me know if it changed anything?

Comment: Yes, now it no longer works for me too. I've tested with two IE11 installations. On one I could reproduce above named situation: The error only occurs when the developer toolbar is open. On the other I could reproduce this even if the developer toolbar isn't open. This is very very strange. I'll submit this as a bug to Microsoft.

Comment: I've submitted this as a bug to Microsoft. Please open [the bug report](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8727426/) and click "Me too"! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with DOM.normalize() but if you're already using jQuery, manipulating the contents of an element is quite easy.  My favorite way to remove unnecessary nested tags like this is to use $.text() like so:

```
$("table tbody tr span").each(function() {
  var $parent = $(this).parent();
  $parent.html($parent.text());
});
```

This works if your use case is indeed as simple as what you posted.  There are a number of other ways to do this type of thing for more complex use cases.